# Real time thread synchronization with normal threads

Tags: java, synchronization, real-time, real-time-java

How would one synchronize one real-time thread with a normal thread in Java? Take for example a real-time thread that calculates some temperatures and the GUI thread that has to collect those numbers and show them on some controls.

The implementation of the real-time library shouldn't matter as it should follow the specifications.

Answer (score 4):

You're going to need two things.  You want your real-time thread to get priority, and preferably have it driven by a timer so you get (nearly) periodic measurements.  Then, you're going to want a resource that can be used to communicate the values.  That can either be a simple monitor, with a critical section so the timer thread can write into it, or it could be -- and very probably would be better as -- a FIFO, so that the GUI thread can eat up values whenever it has cycles.

In Java, the GUI (at least in Swing and similar) is already running a separate thread for UI interactions, so you're big issue is to set up your measurement thread.  Have a look at Runnables.

Answer (score 2):

To use real-time threads you need Real Time Java on real time operating system. http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp

However if you have a thread which is latency sensitive, I suggest you;

- use the concurrency libraries in communications with other threads.
- minimise any GC activity (esp full GCs)
- don't run the thread in the same process as a GUI if you can (as it tends grab a lot of resources in ways you have limited control over)

Answer (score 2):

Since others have brought up RTSJ, I'll comment that synchronization between real-time and non-real-time code has a number of solutions.  RTSJ provides [wait-free queues](http://www.rtsj.org/specjavadoc/javax/realtime/WaitFreeDequeue.html) for such communication.  It is also possible to build upon these or other queues and make use of RTSJ's `AsyncEvent` and `AsyncEventHandler` abstractions to manage the communication.  This is appropriate for situations where you really, truly have a need for deterministic behavior for the "real-time" thread.

If you can accept best-effort behavior (try really hard to hit your deadlines, but the world doesn't fall apart if you miss) I suggest building carefully on the executor framework provided by [the Java concurrency utilities](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/index.html).  A careful selection of task boundaries, a suitable queuing policy (here, "suitable" would depend on more detail about your application than you've given), and threadpool policy will get what you need.